# ¿Qué es una función y qué es un constructor del lenguaje en PHP?

Tags: php

En el Manual de PHP podemos encontrar afirmaciones como esta:

> **`list()`** se utiliza para asignar una lista de variables
>   en una sola operación. Al igual que `array()`, **no es realmente una función, es un constructor del lenguaje**.
>
> [<sub>Explicación de `list()` en el Manual de PHP</sub>](http://php.net/manual/es/function.list.php)

Siempre me llama la atención cuando el Manual hace hincapié en esa **diferencia**. Yo imagino que un constructor del lenguaje sería una especie de función interna, mientras que una función sería las que crea el programador, pero no me queda del todo claro.

Agradecería alguna respuesta que me saque de dudas.

Comment: He encontrado una explicacion aquí: https://diego.com.es/constructores-del-lenguaje-y-constantes-en-php. Lo explica en el punto 1

Comment: Las funciones no solo las crea el programador. PHP provee de una inmensa cantidad de funciones que no son `constructores del lenguaje`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Resumiendo: el constructor de lenguaje son las piezas de Lego que tienes. Las funciones son las combinaciones de piezas con las que implementas funcionalidades.

---

Los constructores de lenguaje son las palabras fundamentales que configuran un lenguaje de programación. En PHP estos serían `if`, `while`... Están *hardcodeados* en el lenguaje y tienen unas reglas especiales. Las funciones se crean a partir de estos constructores.

Dicho de otra manera, de la misma manera que el código PHP se debe descomponer en lenguaje de más bajo nivel para que el servidor lo entienda, el *parser* de PHP descompone las funciones en constructores de lenguaje antes de analizarlas.

Una de las consecuencias es que su invocación es más rápida que las funciones predefinidas o definidas por el usuario. ¿Por qué? Pues porque ls funciones se interpretan a partir de su disección en todos los constructores que forman.

Por ejemplo, cuando intentas acceder a una variable que no existe, recibes un error. Para validar si existe una variable antes de acceder a ella, debe consultar `isset` o `empty`:

```
if (isset ($foo))
```

Si `isset()` fuera una función normal, te daría un warning ya que estás accediendo a $foo para pasarlo a la función `isset()`. Dado que `isset()` es un constructor de lenguaje, sin embargo, esto funciona sin lanzar ese warning. Es por eso que la documentación hace una clara distinción entre funciones normales y constructores de lenguaje.

---

El listado de constructores de lenguaje viene dado en [Lista de palabras reservadas](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.keywords.php) de la web de PHP:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Fuentes:

- respuestas a [What is the difference between a language construct and a “built-in” function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1180184/1983854)
- respuestas a [PHP: What are language constructs and why do we need them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3254327/1983854)
- [What is difference between language construct and functions in php?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-language-construct-and-functions-in-php)

Comment: Entonces no era como yo pensaba. Muchísimas gracias.