# ¿Cómo se llama los nombre propios de PHP?

Tags: php

Yo entiendo cómo nombres a variable o parámetro a nombres creados por nosotros **ejemplo:**

```
$hola = "Hola";
```

Pero a los nombres propios de **PHP** cómo se llaman **ejemplo de nombres propios:**

```
function, echo, global, for, while, if, else
```

Comment: Son conocidos como "keywords" en Ingles, o ["palabras reservadas"](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.keywords.php) en Español.

Comment: Para mi son palabras reservadas

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué es una función y qué es un constructor del lenguaje en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86678/qu%c3%a9-es-una-funci%c3%b3n-y-qu%c3%a9-es-un-constructor-del-lenguaje-en-php)

Comment: @A.Cedano Al parecer la respuesta de esa pregunta se basa a mi pregunta, pero no la pregunta, la pregunta está descrita diferentemente, solo la respuesta de la pregunta se basa a mi pregunta... PERO EN MI PREGUNTA SE BASA A DOS A LA VEZ A DOS NOMBRES, NOMBRE CREADOR POR NOSOTROS Y NOMBRES PROPIOS DE PHP

Comment: @A.Cedano Es decir estoy o no en lo correcto las variables y parámetros son los nombres creados por uno ejm. `$hola $otro` ahora los nombres propios de **PHP** se dice que se llama palabras **RESERVADAS**

Comment: Los nombres que nosotros creamos se llaman variables `$miVariable` o funciones `function myFunction ()...`  y los nombres de PHP se llaman variables reservadas o construcciones del lenguaje.

Comment: @A.Cedano Perfecto gracias amigo, tanto tiempo viendo códigos y hoy me dio está curiosidad.

Comment: @J.Mick FYI: escribir en mayúsculas = gritar.

Comment: @fredyfx hmmm no lo sabía jaja realmente lo realice para que resaltara en el texto.

Answer (score 1):

Se llaman **PALABRAS RESERVADAS**

Estas listas incluyen tanto palabras reservadas como variables predefinidas, constantes y nombres de clases.

Se les define como palabras reservadas, ya que son propias del lenguaje y son utilizadas para acceder a funciones, métodos y/o variables, es por eso que nosotros no las podemos ni debemos utilizar para la creación de nuestras variables y/o métodos.

Aquí puedes encontrar la lista para **[PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.php)**

Comment: Y las variables y parámetros se llaman así a las escritas con nombres creados, ($hola, $otro)? @M.Gress

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta espero quede más claro.

Comment: Está claro, pero falto esté detalle [de esté comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90192/c%C3%B3mo-se-llama-los-nombre-propios-de-php?noredirect=1#comment165881_90192) para aclarar de todo mi pregunta.